# Is there Live Listen for Android?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, accessibility

iOS has an option in their Settings --> Accessibility --> Hearing Aids settings called Live Listen that allows you to listen from the device's microphone in your hearing aids. Is there anything like this in Android?

What I'm trying to input, through the TRRS input, is audio from a communications 2-way radio to hear in my hearing aids' through the Bluetooth connection. I've tried Bluetooth adapters that claim to pair with hearing aids, but have not found any that do, in fact, pair with my hearing aids. My HA's pair easily with my Galaxy A51 phone.

Comment: Just confirming you've tried from `Settings->Accessibility->Hearing enhancements->Amplify ambient sound` (as seen on my Samsung S9 Android 10).

Comment: Thanks very much. I hadn't thought to look in Accessibility, since you don't go through that setting to connect to bluetooth like in iOS. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: As an update on this, the “Amplify Ambient Sound” setting only works with the use of headphones. Whenever I tried to start the function, it generated a message saying that hearing aids were connected and to connect headphones instead. I’m still looking for  a way to hear audio input to the TRRS connector and hear it through the Bluetooth hearing aids.